Fit tcolorbox to table
I am trying to make the tcolorbox to fit its content, a table, and not to span to textwidth . I've look through a lot of questions (1,2,3,4) but nothing seem to work, i tried tabularx too.
Unless I manually adjust the text width but then the footnotes also disappears.
I believe its something very simple but I can't see where is my mistake.

\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,cmyk,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{varwidth}


\tcbset{tab2/.style={
        enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,coltitle=black,center title}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \rowcolors{2}{MistyRose1}{MistyRose1!30!white}

%\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2, hbox, % text width=0.5\textwidth, 
    tabulars={lc}
    ,center,center title,title=Tabela Nutricional Semanal,boxrule=0.75pt,]
    %\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
    %\begin{tabularx}{lX}
    
    {\textbf{Alimento}} & {\textbf{Quantidade (g)}} 
    %& \multirow{2}{=}{\textbf{Recomendado pela (g)}} 
    \\  %\hline
    Carne & 200\\ % & 392 \\
    Gorduras & 170\\ % & 270 \\
    Queijo Quark & 100 \\ %& ND\\
    Pão & 2'450   \\
    Açúcar\footnote{This is the footnote} & 80  \\
    Geleia & 100  \\
    Cereais & 150  \\
    Farinha & 125  \\
    Substituto de café & 63  \\
    %Batatas & 3'500  \\
    %Leite desnatado & 1'250  \\
    %Nabo-sueco & 2'000 & \\
    %Mingau de centeio & 400  \\
    %\midrule
    Total (kcal) & 7'450 \\%& 18'900 \\
    %\end{tabularx} 
    %\end{varwidth}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


Is \begin{tcolorbox}[tab2, tabulars={lc},center title,title=Tabela Nutricional Semanal,boxrule=0.75pt, text width=0.5\textwidth] what you are looking for? It will place the footnotes at the bottom of the box

Yes... but that will require me to adjust the text width every time I have more or less text inside the table, or if I later need to increase font size etc.

Since you have a note inside the table I'd use threeparttable, setting no border separators for the tcolorbox:
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,cmyk,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\tcbset{
    tab2/.style={
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white,
        colframe=red!50!black,
        colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
        coltitle=black,
        center title,
        boxrule=0.75pt,
        hbox,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=.1pt, right=.1pt, 
        toptitle=4pt, bottomtitle=4pt,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{MistyRose1}{MistyRose1!30!white}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    tab2, 
    title=Tabela Nutricional Semanal,
    ]
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \textbf{Alimento} & \textbf{Quantidade (g)} \\
        Carne & 200\\ % & 392 \\
        Gorduras & 170\\ % & 270 \\
        Queijo Quark & 100 \\ %& ND\\
        Pão & 2'450   \\
        Açúcar\tnote{1} & 80  \\
        Geleia & 100  \\
        Cereais & 150  \\
        Farinha & 125  \\
        Substituto de café & 63  \\
        Total (kcal) & 7'450 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize\item[1]  This is the footnote
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable} 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



Aha! Many thanks. I'v tried threeparttable , but for some reason I  had the option flushleft on the package load and this was preventing the tcolorbox to fit.

@G.Bay Thank you for accepting my answer!
